# Does the union of two subgroups being a subgroup imply that they are subsets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I saw this exercise in a book, not sure if is as trivial as I'm imagining:

Let $G$ be a group. Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Now, if $H \cup K$ is a subgroup, does this imply that $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H$.

I believe the answer is yes, however is it this trivial:

Since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ they must both contain the unique identity element, $e$, which means $e \in H$ and $e \in K$. Therefore it is immediate that $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H$?

Comment: Why would it be "immediate"?

Comment: Now that I took a second look at it, I don't actually think I approached this correctly. Because $K$ could contain more elements than $e$, which would have to be shown to also be in $H$.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 5):

What you've written isn't a full proof -- to show that $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H$, you'd need to show that *every element* of $H$ is inside $K$ (or that every element of $K$ is inside $H$), not just that one particular element of $H$ is inside $K$.

For a hint on how to prove this, assume the contrary -- i.e. that there exists $x\in H$ that's not in $K$ and $y\in K$ that's not in $H$. See if you can construct something that would be in $H\cup K$ (if it is a subgroup), but can't be in $H$ or $K$.

Comment: Indeed. I noticed that shortly after posting. I'm sure you could do a proof by contradiction, but not sure how to do it directly.

Comment: @user699279 Yep -- contradiction should work (I've added a bit of an outline to my answer). I imagine for directly, you could start by assuming that $H\not\subset K$ and derive that $K\subset H$, but contradiction is nicer from a "symmetry of argument" perspective.

Comment: Yeah better off just doing a contradiction, i'll hopefully work something out in that regard

Comment: You can conclude, using the properties of unions, that an element like $hk$ that is in $H \cup K$ must be either in $H$ or $K$. Then, $h^{-1}(hk)=k \in H$, and do the same for $K$. I think that works

Comment: @user699279 I think you might want to flesh out the quantifiers a bit, but this seems like the right structure.